# is inputted point within the rectangle centered on the (0,0) axis

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to write a simple python program to determine if two points (x, y) input by a user fall within a rectangle centered on the (0,0) axis with a width of 10 and height of 5.

Here is where I am.

```
x = eval(input("Enter the x point : "))
y = eval(input("Enter the y point : "))


if  x <= 10.0 / 2:
    if y <= 5.0 / 2:
        print("Point (" + str(x) + ", " + str(y) + ") is in the rectangle")
else:
    print("Point (" + str(x) + ", " + str(y) + ") is not in the rectangle")
```

This wont work on the negative side.  There is a math function I am needing, just can't figure out which one.

I have added a distance = math.sqrt (( x * x ) + ( y * y )) and changed the ifs to distance instead of x and y.  I am just so confused.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please tell us what you have tried and we will be glad to help you out...

Comment: I guess you want [`abs()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=abs#abs)

Answer (score 0):

```
WIDTH = 10
HEIGHT = 5
X_CENTER = 0
Y_CENTER = 0

x_str = input("Enter the x point: ")
y_str = input("Enter the y point: ")
x = float(x_str)
y = float(y_str)

is_in = True
if not (X_CENTER - WIDTH/2 <= x <= X_CENTER + WIDTH/2):
    is_in = False
if not (Y_CENTER - HEIGHT/2 <= y <= Y_CENTER + HEIGHT/2):
    is_in = False
if is_in:
    statement = "is"
else:
    statement = "is not"
print("Point (%s, %s) %s in the rectangle." % (x_str, y_str, statement))
```